# No constraints for the design eventhoug I have specified(marked as target) the constraint file

Tags: keyboard, vhdl, vivado

I have a school project in which I need to create a communication between a USB HID keyboard and Nexys4DDR in VHDL using Vivado 2018.3 . I have used  the Nexys 4 keyboard demo from [here](https://reference.digilentinc.com/learn/programmable-logic/tutorials/nexys-4-ddr-keyboard-demo/start) which I wrote in VHDL and to which I have added a DCD in order to decode the values and to output the correct letter. My issue is with the bit stream generation. The error I get is  only when running the bit stream generation and it does not appear in synthesis or implementation.

> WARNING: [Constraints 18-5210] No constraints selected for write.
> Resolution: This message can indicate that there are no constraints for the design, or it can indicate that the used_in flags are set such that the constraints are ignored. This later case is used when running synth_design to not write synthesis constraints to the resulting checkpoint. Instead, project constraints are read when the synthesized design is opened.

I have used the same constraint file as it is specified on the program from diligent.
I am unsure where the issue is.

My constraint file is :

```
## Clock signal
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E3    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { Clk }]; #IO_L12P_T1_MRCC_35 Sch=clk100mhz
create_clock -add -name sys_clk_pin -period 10.00 -waveform {0 5} [get_ports {Clk}];


##Switches

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[0] }]; #IO_L24N_T3_RS0_15 Sch=sw[0]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN L16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[1] }]; #IO_L3N_T0_DQS_EMCCLK_14 Sch=sw[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN M13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[2] }]; #IO_L6N_T0_D08_VREF_14 Sch=sw[2]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[3] }]; #IO_L13N_T2_MRCC_14 Sch=sw[3]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[4] }]; #IO_L12N_T1_MRCC_14 Sch=sw[4]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[5] }]; #IO_L7N_T1_D10_14 Sch=sw[5]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[6] }]; #IO_L17N_T2_A13_D29_14 Sch=sw[6]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[7] }]; #IO_L5N_T0_D07_14 Sch=sw[7]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T8    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS18 } [get_ports { SW[8] }]; #IO_L24N_T3_34 Sch=sw[8]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U8    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS18 } [get_ports { SW[9] }]; #IO_25_34 Sch=sw[9]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[10] }]; #IO_L15P_T2_DQS_RDWR_B_14 Sch=sw[10]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[11] }]; #IO_L23P_T3_A03_D19_14 Sch=sw[11]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN H6    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[12] }]; #IO_L24P_T3_35 Sch=sw[12]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U12   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[13] }]; #IO_L20P_T3_A08_D24_14 Sch=sw[13]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U11   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[14] }]; #IO_L19N_T3_A09_D25_VREF_14 Sch=sw[14]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN V10   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SW[15] }]; #IO_L21P_T3_DQS_14 Sch=sw[15]


## LEDs

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN H17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[0] }]; #IO_L18P_T2_A24_15 Sch=led[0]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN K15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[1] }]; #IO_L24P_T3_RS1_15 Sch=led[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[2] }]; #IO_L17N_T2_A25_15 Sch=led[2]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN N14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[3] }]; #IO_L8P_T1_D11_14 Sch=led[3]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[4] }]; #IO_L7P_T1_D09_14 Sch=led[4]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN V17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[5] }]; #IO_L18N_T2_A11_D27_14 Sch=led[5]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[6] }]; #IO_L17P_T2_A14_D30_14 Sch=led[6]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[7] }]; #IO_L18P_T2_A12_D28_14 Sch=led[7]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN V16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[8] }]; #IO_L16N_T2_A15_D31_14 Sch=led[8]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[9] }]; #IO_L14N_T2_SRCC_14 Sch=led[9]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[10] }]; #IO_L22P_T3_A05_D21_14 Sch=led[10]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[11] }]; #IO_L15N_T2_DQS_DOUT_CSO_B_14 Sch=led[11]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN V15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[12] }]; #IO_L16P_T2_CSI_B_14 Sch=led[12]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN V14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[13] }]; #IO_L22N_T3_A04_D20_14 Sch=led[13]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN V12   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[14] }]; #IO_L20N_T3_A07_D23_14 Sch=led[14]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN V11   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED[15] }]; #IO_L21N_T3_DQS_A06_D22_14 Sch=led[15]

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R12   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED16_B }]; #IO_L5P_T0_D06_14 Sch=led16_b
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN M16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED16_G }]; #IO_L10P_T1_D14_14 Sch=led16_g
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN N15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED16_R }]; #IO_L11P_T1_SRCC_14 Sch=led16_r
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED17_B }]; #IO_L15N_T2_DQS_ADV_B_15 Sch=led17_b
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R11   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED17_G }]; #IO_0_14 Sch=led17_g
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN N16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { LED17_R }]; #IO_L11N_T1_SRCC_14 Sch=led17_r


##7 segment display

set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T10   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SEG[0] }]; #IO_L24N_T3_A00_D16_14 Sch=ca
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R10   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SEG[1] }]; #IO_25_14 Sch=cb
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN K16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SEG[2] }]; #IO_25_15 Sch=cc
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN K13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SEG[3] }]; #IO_L17P_T2_A26_15 Sch=cd
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN P15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SEG[4] }]; #IO_L13P_T2_MRCC_14 Sch=ce
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T11   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SEG[5] }]; #IO_L19P_T3_A10_D26_14 Sch=cf
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN L18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SEG[6] }]; #IO_L4P_T0_D04_14 Sch=cg

set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN H15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { DP }]; #IO_L19N_T3_A21_VREF_15 Sch=dp

set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { AN[0] }]; #IO_L23P_T3_FOE_B_15 Sch=an[0]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { AN[1] }]; #IO_L23N_T3_FWE_B_15 Sch=an[1]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T9    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { AN[2] }]; #IO_L24P_T3_A01_D17_14 Sch=an[2]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { AN[3] }]; #IO_L19P_T3_A22_15 Sch=an[3]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN P14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { AN[4] }]; #IO_L8N_T1_D12_14 Sch=an[4]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { AN[5] }]; #IO_L14P_T2_SRCC_14 Sch=an[5]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN K2    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { AN[6] }]; #IO_L23P_T3_35 Sch=an[6]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { AN[7] }]; #IO_L23N_T3_A02_D18_14 Sch=an[7]


##Buttons

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C12   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { CPU_RESETN }]; #IO_L3P_T0_DQS_AD1P_15 Sch=cpu_resetn

set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN N17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { Rst }]; #IO_L9P_T1_DQS_14 Sch=btnc(Rst)
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN M18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { BTNU }]; #IO_L4N_T0_D05_14 Sch=btnu
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN P17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { BTNL }]; #IO_L12P_T1_MRCC_14 Sch=btnl
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN M17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { BTNR }]; #IO_L10N_T1_D15_14 Sch=btnr
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN P18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { BTND }]; #IO_L9N_T1_DQS_D13_14 Sch=btnd


##Pmod Headers


##Pmod Header JA

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[1] }]; #IO_L20N_T3_A19_15 Sch=ja[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[2] }]; #IO_L21N_T3_DQS_A18_15 Sch=ja[2]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[3] }]; #IO_L21P_T3_DQS_15 Sch=ja[3]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[4] }]; #IO_L18N_T2_A23_15 Sch=ja[4]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[7] }]; #IO_L16N_T2_A27_15 Sch=ja[7]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[8] }]; #IO_L16P_T2_A28_15 Sch=ja[8]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN F18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[9] }]; #IO_L22N_T3_A16_15 Sch=ja[9]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JA[10] }]; #IO_L22P_T3_A17_15 Sch=ja[10]


##Pmod Header JB

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JB[1] }]; #IO_L1P_T0_AD0P_15 Sch=jb[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN F16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JB[2] }]; #IO_L14N_T2_SRCC_15 Sch=jb[2]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JB[3] }]; #IO_L13N_T2_MRCC_15 Sch=jb[3]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN H14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JB[4] }]; #IO_L15P_T2_DQS_15 Sch=jb[4]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JB[7] }]; #IO_L11N_T1_SRCC_15 Sch=jb[7]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN F13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JB[8] }]; #IO_L5P_T0_AD9P_15 Sch=jb[8]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JB[9] }]; #IO_0_15 Sch=jb[9]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN H16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JB[10] }]; #IO_L13P_T2_MRCC_15 Sch=jb[10]


##Pmod Header JC

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN K1    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JC[1] }]; #IO_L23N_T3_35 Sch=jc[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN F6    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JC[2] }]; #IO_L19N_T3_VREF_35 Sch=jc[2]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J2    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JC[3] }]; #IO_L22N_T3_35 Sch=jc[3]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G6    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JC[4] }]; #IO_L19P_T3_35 Sch=jc[4]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E7    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JC[7] }]; #IO_L6P_T0_35 Sch=jc[7]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J3    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JC[8] }]; #IO_L22P_T3_35 Sch=jc[8]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J4    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JC[9] }]; #IO_L21P_T3_DQS_35 Sch=jc[9]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E6    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JC[10] }]; #IO_L5P_T0_AD13P_35 Sch=jc[10]


##Pmod Header JD

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN H4    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JD[1] }]; #IO_L21N_T3_DQS_35 Sch=jd[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN H1    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JD[2] }]; #IO_L17P_T2_35 Sch=jd[2]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G1    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JD[3] }]; #IO_L17N_T2_35 Sch=jd[3]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G3    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JD[4] }]; #IO_L20N_T3_35 Sch=jd[4]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN H2    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JD[7] }]; #IO_L15P_T2_DQS_35 Sch=jd[7]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G4    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JD[8] }]; #IO_L20P_T3_35 Sch=jd[8]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN G2    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JD[9] }]; #IO_L15N_T2_DQS_35 Sch=jd[9]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN F3    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { JD[10] }]; #IO_L13N_T2_MRCC_35 Sch=jd[10]


##Pmod Header JXADC

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A14   IOSTANDARD LVDS     } [get_ports { XA_N[1] }]; #IO_L9N_T1_DQS_AD3N_15 Sch=xa_n[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A13   IOSTANDARD LVDS     } [get_ports { XA_P[1] }]; #IO_L9P_T1_DQS_AD3P_15 Sch=xa_p[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A16   IOSTANDARD LVDS     } [get_ports { XA_N[2] }]; #IO_L8N_T1_AD10N_15 Sch=xa_n[2]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A15   IOSTANDARD LVDS     } [get_ports { XA_P[2] }]; #IO_L8P_T1_AD10P_15 Sch=xa_p[2]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B17   IOSTANDARD LVDS     } [get_ports { XA_N[3] }]; #IO_L7N_T1_AD2N_15 Sch=xa_n[3]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B16   IOSTANDARD LVDS     } [get_ports { XA_P[3] }]; #IO_L7P_T1_AD2P_15 Sch=xa_p[3]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A18   IOSTANDARD LVDS     } [get_ports { XA_N[4] }]; #IO_L10N_T1_AD11N_15 Sch=xa_n[4]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B18   IOSTANDARD LVDS     } [get_ports { XA_P[4] }]; #IO_L10P_T1_AD11P_15 Sch=xa_p[4]


##VGA Connector

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A3    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_R[0] }]; #IO_L8N_T1_AD14N_35 Sch=vga_r[0]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B4    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_R[1] }]; #IO_L7N_T1_AD6N_35 Sch=vga_r[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C5    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_R[2] }]; #IO_L1N_T0_AD4N_35 Sch=vga_r[2]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A4    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_R[3] }]; #IO_L8P_T1_AD14P_35 Sch=vga_r[3]

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C6    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_G[0] }]; #IO_L1P_T0_AD4P_35 Sch=vga_g[0]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A5    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_G[1] }]; #IO_L3N_T0_DQS_AD5N_35 Sch=vga_g[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B6    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_G[2] }]; #IO_L2N_T0_AD12N_35 Sch=vga_g[2]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A6    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_G[3] }]; #IO_L3P_T0_DQS_AD5P_35 Sch=vga_g[3]

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B7    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_B[0] }]; #IO_L2P_T0_AD12P_35 Sch=vga_b[0]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C7    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_B[1] }]; #IO_L4N_T0_35 Sch=vga_b[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D7    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_B[2] }]; #IO_L6N_T0_VREF_35 Sch=vga_b[2]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D8    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_B[3] }]; #IO_L4P_T0_35 Sch=vga_b[3]

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B11   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_HS }]; #IO_L4P_T0_15 Sch=vga_hs
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B12   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { VGA_VS }]; #IO_L3N_T0_DQS_AD1N_15 Sch=vga_vs


##Micro SD Connector

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E2    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SD_RESET }]; #IO_L14P_T2_SRCC_35 Sch=sd_reset
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A1    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SD_CD }]; #IO_L9N_T1_DQS_AD7N_35 Sch=sd_cd
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B1    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SD_SCK }]; #IO_L9P_T1_DQS_AD7P_35 Sch=sd_sck
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C1    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SD_CMD }]; #IO_L16N_T2_35 Sch=sd_cmd
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C2    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SD_DAT[0] }]; #IO_L16P_T2_35 Sch=sd_dat[0]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E1    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SD_DAT[1] }]; #IO_L18N_T2_35 Sch=sd_dat[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN F1    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SD_DAT[2] }]; #IO_L18P_T2_35 Sch=sd_dat[2]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D2    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { SD_DAT[3] }]; #IO_L14N_T2_SRCC_35 Sch=sd_dat[3]


##Accelerometer

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { ACL_MISO }]; #IO_L11P_T1_SRCC_15 Sch=acl_miso
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN F14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { ACL_MOSI }]; #IO_L5N_T0_AD9N_15 Sch=acl_mosi
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN F15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { ACL_SCLK }]; #IO_L14P_T2_SRCC_15 Sch=acl_sclk
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { ACL_CSN }]; #IO_L12P_T1_MRCC_15 Sch=acl_csn
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { ACL_INT[1] }]; #IO_L2P_T0_AD8P_15 Sch=acl_int[1]
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { ACL_INT[2] }]; #IO_L20P_T3_A20_15 Sch=acl_int[2]


##Temperature Sensor

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { TMP_SCL }]; #IO_L1N_T0_AD0N_15 Sch=tmp_scl
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { TMP_SDA }]; #IO_L12N_T1_MRCC_15 Sch=tmp_sda
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { TMP_INT }]; #IO_L6N_T0_VREF_15 Sch=tmp_int
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { TMP_CT }]; #IO_L2N_T0_AD8N_15 Sch=tmp_ct

##Omnidirectional Microphone

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J5    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { M_CLK }]; #IO_25_35 Sch=m_clk
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN H5    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { M_DATA }]; #IO_L24N_T3_35 Sch=m_data
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN F5    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { M_LRSEL }]; #IO_0_35 Sch=m_lrsel


##PWM Audio Amplifier

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN A11   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { AUD_PWM }]; #IO_L4N_T0_15 Sch=aud_pwm
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D12   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { AUD_SD }]; #IO_L6P_T0_15 Sch=aud_sd


##USB-RS232 Interface

#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN C4    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { UART_TXD_IN }]; #IO_L7P_T1_AD6P_35 Sch=uart_txd_in
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D4    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { UART_TXD }]; #IO_L11N_T1_SRCC_35 Sch=uart_rxd_out
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN D3    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { UART_CTS }]; #IO_L12N_T1_MRCC_35 Sch=uart_cts
#set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E5    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { UART_RTS }]; #IO_L5N_T0_AD13N_35 Sch=uart_rts

##USB HID (PS/2)

set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN F4    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { PS2_clk }]; #IO_L13P_T2_MRCC_35 Sch=ps2_clk
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN B2    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { PS2_data }]; #IO_L10N_T1_AD15N_35 Sch=ps2_data
```

The main program is connected to a PS2 receiver, decoder and a 7 segment display.

```
entity top is
Port ( 
Clk: in std_logic;
Rst: in std_logic;
PS2_clk: in std_logic;
PS2_data: in std_logic;
SEG: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
AN: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
DP: out std_logic;
UART_TXD: out std_logic
);
end top;

architecture Behavioral of top is
signal smallerCLK:std_logic:='0';
signal keycode: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
component PS2RECEIVER is 
Port    ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           kclk : in STD_LOGIC;
           kdata : in STD_LOGIC;
           outData : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end component;

component DCD is
 Port (
 input: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
 CLK: in std_logic;
 output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
  );
end component DCD;
signal output:  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin

process(clk)
begin
smallerCLK<=NOT smallerCLK;
end process;
PS2: PS2RECEIVER port map (smallerCLK,PS2_CLK,PS2_DATA,keycode);

DC:DCD port map(keycode,smallerCLK,output);
display: entity WORK.displ7seg
            port map(Clk => Clk,
                     Rst => Rst,
                     Data => output,
                     An => An,
                     Seg => Seg);

end Behavioral;
```

The PS2 receiver which is connected to a debouncer:

```
entity PS2Receiver is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           kclk : in STD_LOGIC;
           kdata : in STD_LOGIC;
           outData : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end PS2Receiver;

architecture Behavioral of PS2Receiver is
signal kclkf: std_logic;
signal kdataf: std_logic;
signal datacur: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal dataprev: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal cnt: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000"; 
signal keycode: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0):= (Others => '0');
signal flag: std_logic:='0';

component debouncer is
port(CLK: in std_logic;
     I0: in std_logic;
     I1: in std_logic;
    O0: out std_logic;
    O1:out std_logic );
end component;

begin

Deb: debouncer port map(clk=>clk,I0=>kclk,I1=>kdata,O0=>kclkf,O1=>kdataf);



process(clk)
begin 
    if falling_edge(kclkf) then
       case cnt is 
              when "0000" => null ; --do nothing is the starting bit--0
            when "0001" => datacur<=datacur(7 downto 1) & kdataf;--1
         when "0010" => datacur<=datacur(7 downto 2) & kdataf & datacur(0);--2
       when "0011" => datacur<=datacur(7 downto 3) & kdataf & datacur(1 downto 0);--3
              when "0100" => datacur<=datacur(7 downto 4) & kdataf & datacur(2 downto 0);--4
           when "0101" => datacur<=datacur(7 downto 5) & kdataf & datacur(3 downto 0);---5
            when "0110" => datacur<=datacur(7 downto 6) & kdataf & datacur(4 downto 0);--6
             when "0111" => datacur<=datacur(7) & kdataf & datacur(5 downto 0);--7
            when "1000" => datacur<= kdataf & datacur(6 downto 0);--8
            when "1001" => flag<='1';--9
            when "1010" => flag<='0';--10
             when others=> NULL;
       end case;
       if(cnt <= 9) then cnt<= cnt+1;
        elsif cnt=10 then cnt<=(Others => '0');
      end if;
end if; 
end process;

process(flag)
begin 
    if rising_edge(flag) then 
        if NOT(dataprev = datacur) then 
           keycode(31 downto 24)<= keycode(23 downto 16);
           keycode(23 downto 16)<= keycode(15 downto 8);
           keycode(15 downto 8)<= dataprev;
           keycode(7 downto 0)<= datacur;
           dataprev<= datacur;           
            end if;
        end if;
end process;

outData<=keycode;


end Behavioral;



entity Debouncer is
 Port (
 CLK: in std_logic;
 I0: in std_logic;
 I1: in std_logic;
 O0: out std_logic;
 O1:out std_logic );
end Debouncer;

architecture Behavioral of Debouncer is
signal cnt0: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):="00000"; 
signal cnt1: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0):="00000"; 
signal Iv1: std_logic:='0';
signal Iv0: std_logic:='0';
signal out0:std_logic;
signal out1: std_logic;

begin

process(clk)
begin
   if rising_edge(clk) then
    if(I0=Iv0)then
        if cnt0="10011" then O0<=I0;
            else cnt0<=cnt0+"00001";
        end if;
        else 
            cnt0<="00000";
            Iv0<= I0;
        end if;
    if(I1=Iv1)then
        if cnt1="10011" then O1<=I1;
            else cnt1<=cnt1+"00001";
        end if;
        else 
            cnt1<="00000";
            Iv1<= I1;
        end if;    
         
       end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

And the DCD is :

```
entity DCD is
 Port (
 input: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
 CLK: in std_logic;
 output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
  );
end DCD;

architecture Behavioral of DCD is
signal AUX : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin

process(clk)
begin
case input is 
        
         when "00000000000000000000000001000101"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000011000000"; --0
       when "00000000000000000000000000010110"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000011111001"; --1 
         when "00000000000000000000000000011110"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010100100"; --2
         when "00000000000000000000000000100110"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010110000"; --3
         when "00000000000000000000000000100101"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010011011"; --4
     when "00000000000000000000000000101110"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010010010"; --5
         when "00000000000000000000000000110110"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010000010"; --6
        when "00000000000000000000000000111101"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000011111000"; --7
       when "00000000000000000000000000111110"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010000000"; --8
       when "00000000000000000000000001000110"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010010000"; --9  
         when "00000000000000000000000000011100"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010001000"; --A     
         when "00000000000000000000000000110010"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010000011"; --b    
         when "00000000000000000000000000100001"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000011000110"; --C        
         when "00000000000000000000000000100011"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010100001"; --d
         when "00000000000000000000000000100100"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010000110"; --E
         when "00000000000000000000000000101011"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010001110"; --F 
         when "00000000000000000000000000110100"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010000010"; --G    
         when "00000000000000000000000000110011"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010001001"; --H     
         when "00000000000000000000000001000011"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000011001111"; --I     
         when "00000000000000000000000000111011"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000011110001"; --J
         when "00000000000000000000000001000010"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010001111"; --K    
         when "00000000000000000000000001001011"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000011000111"; --L    
         when "00000000000000000000000000111010"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000011001000"; --M
         when "00000000000000000000000000110001"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010101011"; --N
         when "00000000000000000000000001000100"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000011000000"; --O    
         when "00000000000000000000000001001101"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010001100"; --P
         when "00000000000000000000000000010101"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010100001"; --Q    
         when "00000000000000000000000000101101"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010101111"; --r     
         when "00000000000000000000000000011011"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010010010"; --S
         when "00000000000000000000000000101100"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010000111"; --t
         when "00000000000000000000000000111100"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000011000001"; --U
         when "00000000000000000000000000101010"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000011010101"; --V                      
         when "00000000000000000000000000011101"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010011001"; --Y
         when "00000000000000000000000000011010"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000010100100"; --Z
         when "00000000000000000000000000101001"=> AUX <="00000000000000000000000001110111"; -- Spaceend case
         when others=> NULL;
end case;

end process;
output<=AUX;

end Behavioral;
```

Has somebody else run into this problem and has a solution  ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but I have a similar setup (Vivado 2019.2 and Nexys 4 (not DDR). I had a very similar issue; I was unable to generate a bitstream. Closer inspection showed that I had this error too after Synthesis. What worked for me was this solution, posted here with the solution by user hongh: [Here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Meaning-of-synthesis-warning-Constraints-18-5210-No-constraint/td-p/881007)

> When you generate the synth.dcp with the below method, the warning
>   disappears and no constraints are missing:
>
> <1>. Open synthesized design
>
> <2>. write_checkpoint synth.dcp
>   (type that command in the TCL console)

After doing these 2 simple steps, I was able to run Implementation and generate a bitstream successfully, as well as program my board. I hope this helps, and good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is that there's an error in your constraint file, so Vivado didn't load it properly. Check log for any warnings mentioning your constraint file.